# Avoiding for loop with cells and matrixes involved

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, cell

I am trying to avoid the for loops and I have been reading through all the old posts there are about it but I am not able to solve my problem. I am new in MATLAB, so apologies for my ignorance.

The thing is that I have a 300x2 cell and in each one I have a 128x128x256 matrix. Each one is an image with 128x128 pixels and 256 channels per pixel. In the first column of the 300x2 cell I have my parallel intensity values and in the second one my perpendicular intensity values.

What I want to do is to take every pixel of every image (for each component) and sum the intensity values channel by channel.

The code I have is the following:

```
Image_par_channels=zeros(128,128,256);
Image_per_channels=zeros(128,128,256);
Image_tot_channels=zeros(128,128,256);
for a=1:128
    for b=1:128
        for j=1:256
            for i=1:numfiles
                Image_par_channels(a,b,j)=Image_par_channels(a,b,j)+Image_cell_par_per{i,1}(a,b,j);
                Image_per_channels(a,b,j)=Image_per_channels(a,b,j)+Image_cell_par_per{i,2}(a,b,j);
            end
            Image_tot_channels(a,b,j)=Image_par_channels(a,b,j)+2*G*Image_per_channels(a,b,j);
        end
    end
end
```

I think I could speed it up introducing (:,:,j) instead of specifying a and b. But still a for loop. I am trying to use cellfun without any success due to my lack of expertise. Could you please give me a hand?

I would really appreciate it.

Many thanks and have a nice day!
Y

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like

```
Image_par_channels=zeros(128,128,256);
Image_per_channels=zeros(128,128,256);
Image_tot_channels=zeros(128,128,256);

for i=1:numfiles
     Image_par_channels = Image_par_channels + Image_cell_par_per{i,1};
     Image_per_channels = Image_per_channels + Image_cell_par_per{i,2};
end

Image_tot_channels = Image_par_channels + 2*G*Image_per_channels;
```

I haven't work with matlab in a long time, but I seem to recall you can do something like this. `g` is a constant.

**EDIT:**
Removed the `+=`. Incremental assignment is not an operator available in matlab. You should also note that `Image_tot_channels` can be build directly in the loop, if you don't need the other two variables later.